# How to get datetime in 24hour format from oracle database?

Tags: oracle10g

Is there any other way to get datetime field from oracle database in 24hour format???like
-> "select getxsddate(col_name) from tab_name" will get you datetime format as "2012-04-04T12:31:00"...I wanted to know if there are any other ways as i`m not satisfied with this format.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
select to_char(col_name, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from tab_name
```

You can read more about `to_char` function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm#i1009324)

Comment: Marcin,thanks for the reply,but this didn`t work when I queried like this "select to_char('4/4/2012 00:32:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual"

Comment: Well, you have to provide date (not string) for to_char function. So your example query should rather look like "select to_char(to_date('4/4/2012 00:32:00','fmdd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from dual"

Comment: To be honest, I don't fully understand the question...
If col_name is your date column (i.e. type of this column is DATE) and tab_name is your table,then you can run the query 
"select to_char(col_name, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') from tab_name"
to display the dates in your desired format.

Answer (score 3):

Another very simple way is to set, in the database nls parameters, the parameter date_format='DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: The database NLS parameters are often over-ridden by client settings.  Which means it's never safe for code to rely on server-side NLS format parameters, which means it's almost never worth setting the parameter.

Comment: Yes, it's fair enough.