# How to convert 8pm to 20 hrs in plsql?

Tags: datetime, plsql

Can anyone help me to convert `08-MAR-16 08.15.41.000000 PM` so I need `08-MAR-16 20.15.41.000000` ?

Comment: Is your initial date retrieved from a variable/column that's of DATE datatype, or is it a string?

Comment: I wanted to subtract two timestamps and it doesnt give me acceptable values when using 8PM. That s why I need to convert 8PM to 20 hrs. Below is the sql I used;

select extract(hour from diff) hrs from (
      select TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 08.41.41.000000 PM', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 08.00.00.000000 AM', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF') diff from dual)

Comment: @Boneist, I am using a String value which is like follows; '08-MAR-16 08.15.41.000000 PM'. I want ' 08-MAR-16 20.15.41.000000'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get datetime in 24hour format from oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011935/how-to-get-datetime-in-24hour-format-from-oracle-database)

Comment: @Bishan, No it is not a duplicate. that didnt convert AM/PM value to hrs. please see the string I used. ('08-FEB-19 08.41.41.000000 PM') it includes PM. but in the question it already given in 24 hrs (4/4/2012 00:32:00)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert '2016-07-01 01:12:22 PM' to '2016-07-01 13:12:22' hour format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586807/how-to-convert-2016-07-01-011222-pm-to-2016-07-01-131222-hour-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your answer, you must first convert the string to a date (or, in your case, a timestamp, since you've got sub-seconds present) using the appropriate format model, and then convert it back to a string using the format model appropriate for the output if you absolutely must:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(<date_str>, <string date format>), <output date format>)
```

which means your case would be:

```
to_char(to_timestamp('08-MAR-16 08.15.41.000000 PM', 'dd-MON-rr hh.mi.ss.ff6 AM'),'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss.ff6')
```

I would **highly** recommend you avoid the use of two digit years, though. We went through Y2K to avoid having to guess at which year you're talking about. Is it 2016? 1916? 2116? etc. Be as explicit as you can to avoid Oracle having to guess at what you mean, e.g.:

```
to_char(to_timestamp('08-MAR-2016 08.15.41.000000 PM', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff6 AM'),'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6')
```

Comment: Thanks @Boneist this works for me, what I missed was FF6, instead I have used FF. Thank you very much for the help. I accept this as the answer.